# Image resize when rotate

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to rotate the image.. I have a pictureBox 369x276. But when I rotate, this size decrease.

The pictureBox sizeMode is ***PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage***

here is my code:

```
        Bitmap oldBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
        float angle = 90;
        var newBitmap = new Bitmap(oldBitmap.Width, oldBitmap.Height);

        var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);
        graphics.TranslateTransform((float)oldBitmap.Width  / 2, (float)oldBitmap.Height / 2);
        graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
        graphics.TranslateTransform(-(float)oldBitmap.Width / 2, -(float)oldBitmap.Height / 2);
        graphics.DrawImage(oldBitmap, new Point(0, 0));
        pictureBox1.Image = newBitmap;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use RotateFlip:

```
Bitmap oldBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
oldBitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
pictureBox1.Image = oldBitmap;
```

As @Dan-o has pointed out, this allows a rotation of any of the degree's in the [System.Drawing.RotateFlipType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rotatefliptype.aspx) enum.

To rotate a Bitmap any angle without losing the size, you could do the following, but it's a bit convoluted!

**One** - Add the [WriteableBitmapEx](https://github.com/teichgraf/WriteableBitmapEx/) library to your project

**Two** - Add the XAML, WindowsBase and PresentationCore libraries to your project

**Three** - Use the following to rotate your Bitmap any amount of degrees:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap oldBitmap = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;;

        var bitmapAsWriteableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(BitmapToBitmapImage(oldBitmap));
        bitmapAsWriteableBitmap.RotateFree(23);

        var rotatedImageAsMemoryStream = WriteableBitmapToMemoryStream(bitmapAsWriteableBitmap);
        oldBitmap = new Bitmap(rotatedImageAsMemoryStream);
    }

    public static BitmapImage BitmapToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var memStream = BitmapToMemoryStream(bitmap);
        return MemoryStreamToBitmapImage(memStream);
    }

    public static MemoryStream BitmapToMemoryStream(Bitmap image)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);

        return memoryStream;
    }

    public static BitmapImage MemoryStreamToBitmapImage(MemoryStream ms)
    {
        ms.Position = 0;
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        bitmap.BeginInit();

        bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

        bitmap.EndInit();
        bitmap.Freeze();

        return bitmap;
    }

    private static MemoryStream WriteableBitmapToMemoryStream(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(writeableBitmap));

        encoder.Save(ms);

        return ms;
    }
}
```

Pain in the ass, but works!

Comment: RotateFlip is great if all you want to do is 90-degree rotates.  The op's code can handle any angle.

Comment: @Dan-o Very true, updated my answer with a (slightly long-winded) way to rotate an image by any amount of degrees without affecting the size.

Answer (score 2):

The smaller image size is to be expected.  I've never figured out why, but the `Graphics.DrawImage` really only works if you provide it not only a start location, but also a size.  One of the overloads allows you to include size.